# NSOutlineView selection parent

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, osx-tiger

I got a NSOutlineView and there are a couple items on it. Each one has 3 children(places, photos and social). They all have the same children. Say the user has selected places, does anyone knows how may I detect which item is the parent of the selected item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

-[NSOutlineView selectedRow] (inherited from NSTableView)
-[NSOutlineView itemAtRow:]
-[NSOutlineView parentForItem:]

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work when every item has the same children :(

Comment: They might have children with the same names, but they shouldn't be the same items.  The "Places" item under one parent shouldn't be the same item as the "Places" item under a different parent.

Comment: I do not know if Ken Thomases answers the question but there are some things that have been useful to me in his answer.